# Cannot Run HelloWorld C++ App on Eclipse, Mac OS X? No RunAs Option; GCC Not Installed Despite XCode Installed

Tags: c++

I've spent hours this evening trying to get the hello world C++ App to run and no luck.

What I've Done:
1. Installed XCode and C++ for Eclipse as per http://www.banym.de/mac/install-eclipse-cc-juno-on-mac-os-x
2. Tested that XCode works and can open it

What Happens:
1. When I create a new C++ Hello World project in Eclipse, I have no Run As options. Run As simply does not appear.

[image]

Other Observations:
1. I am not convinced that GCC is really installed on my Mac because when I run "gcc -v" from a terminal I get "-bash: gcc: command not found"
2. When I attempt to go to "/bin/usr/gcc/" there is nothing (which http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/726/mac-os-x-install-gcc-compiler/ implies that GCC is not installed but I know I have XCode installed).

Comment: Have u tried the run button at the top-center?

Comment: Yes. "Unable to Launch. The selection cannot be launched". Why is there no C++ launch option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the commandline tools from XCode.

Comment: This resolves the "gcc -v" commandline issue which is a step in the right direction. For documentation, the Help is at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_3.html  However, I still do not see any Run options available to me within Eclipse.

Comment: Just to share knowledge, I also committed this error: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/226391/  I did not include all the downloads. The main Eclipse overview page is deceptive as it doesn't include all of what you need in its instructions. Now I have the "C++" Run As option but there is another erorr "Launch Failed. Binary Not Found"

Comment: Just to close out the loop, everything works now. I did not right click on the project, click "Build Project" first. I am a new to C++ now so I just assumed you could run it like you do in Java. Do you have to build before each run?

Comment: To summarize for documentation, I needed to: 1. Download XCode 2. Download XCode commandline tools 3. Download the full Eclipse plugin list for C++ (documentation is very deceptive).